# addTextChangedListener onTextChanged count Not working On android version 10

Tags: android, android-10.0, addtextchangedlistener

I use addTextChangedListener to search item from server with retrofit. but only android version 10 onTextChanged count not working...?

**Here is my code**

```
searchEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if (count>1) {
                String name = searchEdit.getText().toString().trim();

                if (!name.isEmpty()) {
                    searchItemByName(name);
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            
        }
    });
```

Comment: When you debug .. Does `onTextChanged` get called?

Comment: I believe you have another issue somewhere in the rest of your code, would you plz supply more details regarding your issue.

Comment: When I debug.... onTextChanged can't get

Comment: I posted an answer, Please check.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe exactly what "not working" means.

Comment: i edit my question. finally its work with "s.length()". thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with the assumption that you're using `count` parameter in `onTextChanged` callback as the number of characters inside your `searchEdit` Edittext.

**Solution:**
You need to use `s.length()` function instead of the parameter `count`, like this:

```
searchEdit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                if (s.length()>1) {
                    String name = searchEdit.getText().toString().trim();

                    if (!name.isEmpty()) {
                        searchItemByName(name);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

**Explanation:**

If you have a look at the documentation of `android.text.TextWatcher::onTextChanged` function below:

```
/**
     * This method is called to notify you that, within <code>s</code>,
     * the <code>count</code> characters beginning at <code>start</code>
     * have just replaced old text that had length <code>before</code>.
     * It is an error to attempt to make changes to <code>s</code> from
     * this callback.
     */
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count);
```

it says that `count` parameter refers to the number of characters changed in `s`, and thus, if you're typing into the edittext your `onTextChanged` function will be called with the parameter `count` is 1.

**Alternatively:** you can use `afterTextChanged` callback with `s.length()`.