# TextWatcher Not working, To use afterTextChaanges or onTextChanged

Tags: android

I've to make a textfield, after entering 6 digits it will automatically call another function.

Here is what is did so far:

```
//In onViewCreated
        binding.etOtp.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
//onViewCreated functions ends

 private val textWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            if (count == 6) {
                val otp=binding.etOtp.text.toString().trim()
                    val credential : PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
                        storedVerificationId.toString(), otp)
                    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
            }
        }
    }



 private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this.requireActivity()) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    startActivity(Intent(activity?.applicationContext, DashboardActivity::class.java))
                    activity?.finish()
                }
            }
    }
```

I got no error, but it is not working.
No suspicious log cat nothing, when I type the 6 digit otp it doesn't do anything.
Just the cursor blinks.
Will I've to write in afterTextChanged.

Comment: `I got no error, but it is not working.` have you tried using breakpoints or logs to figure it out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` is not the length of text here . please check [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher#onTextChanged(java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int)).

You should use `s.length()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using the `count` parameter of your `TextWatcher::onTextChanged` function wrong. You can use `s.length()` instead like this:

```
private val textWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            if (s.length() == 6) {
                val otp=binding.etOtp.text.toString().trim()
                    val credential : PhoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
                        storedVerificationId.toString(), otp)
                    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
            }
        }
    }
```

You can find proper explanation in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65627846/3375081)